# How can I initialize a list of lists to a certain size?

Tags: python, list, append, extend

I'm trying to initialize 'big_list', which is a list containing lists, and we know in advance that there will be 200 lists within 'big_list', and that each list will contain only strings or nothing, and that later in the program there will be a loop that appends (one or more times) to only a certain number of those lists.

Is there a simplest way to go about this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use list comprehension for example:

```
big_list = [[] for _ in range(200)]
```

That will create a list containing 200 **different** lists.

Answer (score -3):

You can multiply lists to achieve what you want to do:

```
big_list = [[]] * 200
```

Gives you a list of 200 empty lists. One caveat is that it will actually be 200 times the same list. This may not be what you want. For example appending to one of the lists will actually append to all, since they are all the same.

So for a list-of-lists, Paulo Bu's approach may be better. The multiplication feature is nice for constructing repeated strings or initializing a list of int's:

```
'A' * 5 -> 'AAAAA'
[0] * 3 -> [0, 0, 0]
```

The fact that the list contains different "names" for the same underlying object is not a problem here, it only becomes troublesome for mutable types, such as lists, dicts, sets, ... (but not the immutable tuples, for example)-

Comment: Try then `big_list[0].append('s')` and see what happens.

Comment: It yields "TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable" any way to fix this?

Comment: @giver: I tried this in Python 2.7 and 3.3, and couldn't reproduce your issue in either of those.

Comment: I think the difference is that I'm trying to append strings, and not just characters. appending a character seems to work, but that's the error I get when trying to append a string....

Comment: No, that's not the issue. ``'ab' * 3 -> 'ababab'``. Can you edit the question to include the code that is now failing for you?

Comment: each time you append to the list it adds the value to all sub-lists